# hylafax probemodem fails to probe USB modem

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev, modem

On Ubuntu 21.04 I'm having trouble adding a USB modem to my Hylafax 6.0.7 installation. It consistently fails to probe on two different USB modems: a USRobotics 5637 and a generic "USB 2.0 56K Modem" with Conexant chipset from Amazon.

Forgive me, I'm sort of a noob.

I've gotten the packages installed and ended up appending the following to `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules` so that Ubuntu would allow me to write to the modem:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
```

I was able to talk to the modems and query the modem classes with cu, and also talk to the modem with screen.

When doing `sudo probemodem`, it hangs after the lights briefly blink on both modems.

`probemodem` is stuck displaying 38400 and does not cycle through each speed unless I unplug the modem and plug it back in. After plugging it back in, the modem will hang on 19200, but sometimes it will cycle all the way through and error out saying that it was `unable to deduce DTE-DCE speed`.

If I use the `probemodem -s` option to lock the speed it also fails for both modems.

It will also hang when specifying a speed. The end result seems to be the same each time: the modem cannot be added to hylafax.

I checked permissions on the devices, and both are `root/dialout` with `rw/rw/rw`.

I also noticed that there is no fax group on my system after installing the `hylafax-server` and `hylafax-client` packages from the Ubuntu repo.

My first guess is that this is somehow permissions related, however I don't know where to start.

- How do I get Hylafax to successfully probe either modem?
- Do I even need udev rules, or did I overlook something when configuring my system?
- Should the absence of a fax group be concerning?
- Where do I go from here?

Comment: Just an idea: before feeding the devices to hylafax, check them yourself with something like `screen /dev/... baud_rate`. If you can talk to them (a `AT<Enter>` will probably do) then you can start thinking about hylafax.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoTrápani the modems both responded to the screen command, so I'm guessing this is probably a hylafax issue.